# How to identify which record in a table has thrown error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I have a table below which have a `varchar` column which is in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
DATECOL
.......
2014-12-01
2014-12-02
2014-12-03
2014-12-04
2014-13-04
```

The last record is a junk data since `13` is not a month and which throws an error
When I execute the following query.

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Here is the query I executed

```
SELECT CAST(DATECOL AS DATE) DDD FROM #TEMP
```

Now how can I know which line has caused error in the table ie, `2014-13-04` is the `5th` record. How can I know that the error has occurred from the `5th` record? This would be useful when handling with a table with millions of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of the function called [`ISDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187347.aspx) , which returns 1 for a value which can be converted to datetime/date and 0 for a value which is a valid datetime/date/time value

**Get Invalid Datetime/Date/Time Values**

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TEMP
WHERE ISDATE(DATECOL) = 0
```

Will return all the values which will error out if you try to convert them to datetime/date data type.

To avoid encountering error when converting data you can do something like

**Convert only Valid Datetime/Date/Time Values**

```
SELECT CAST(DATECOL AS DATE) DDD 
FROM #TEMP
WHERE ISDATE(DATECOL) = 1
```

Comment: Thats working Ali. Now can I get the line number? @M.Ali

Comment: The best solution for this problem is to use appropriate datatype to store data, is possible you should change the datatype of this column to date. Will save you a lot of time and effort in future.